# Validation of Elasticsearch query string in NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We are migrating from Elasticsearch 5.6 to es 7.5. Together with this migration we are migrating NEST library as well.

In 5.6 we were using validations like this:

```cs
...

Nest.ElasticClient client = ...
Nest.QueryContainer query = ...

client.ValidateQuery<T>(v => v.Query(q => query));
```

But according to [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-breaking-changes.html), all methods to validate query were removed from 7.x lib and there is no info how to use NEST client in this case.

Is there some way how to validate our queries using `Nest.ElasticClient` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been moved to `Indices` part of the client methods.

```
client.Indices.ValidateQuery(..)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. You saved my day ;)